# Pick First and Last Child by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a piece of code as below :-

```
<table class="abc">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="scriptWPQ22">
                <table id="Hero-WPQ22" dir="none" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" summary="MeetTheTeam" class="greenroom-meettheteam">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="ms-list-addnew ms-textLarge ms-soften"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div></div>
                <iframe src="javascript:false;" id="FilterIframe49" name="FilterIframe49" style="display:none" height="0" width="0" filterlink="?"></iframe>
                <div class="local-intranets">
                    <div class="local-intranets-title">Budapest
                            </div>
                </div>
                <div class="local-intranets">
                    <div class="local-intranets-title">Moscow</div>
                </div>
                <div class="local-intranets">
                    <div class="local-intranets-title">Stockholm
                                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="local-intranets">
                    <div class="local-intranets-title">Warsaw
                                        </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have to pick first and last local-intranets class by jquery. How to do that. I have no any other specific class of div to pick. I tried first:child and last:child, but its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the css pseudo-class child selector:

```
$('.local-intranets:first-child')
$('.local-intranets:last-child')
```

You can also be more specific:

```
$('#scriptWPQ22 .local-intranets:first-child')
$('#scriptWPQ22 .local-intranets:last-child')
```

Or use the jquery `first` and `last` methods:

```
$('.local-intranets').first()
$('.local-intranets').last()
```

Comment: Is not a first-child in OP html

Comment: Is there a way to do it using CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Use `first` and `last` methods of jquery

```
var $localIntranets = $( ".local-intranets" );
var first = $localIntranets.first();
var last  = $localIntranets.last();
```

**Edit**

You can use [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afirst-child) and `:last-child` as well.

```
var first = $( ".local-intranets:first-child" );
var last  = $( ".local-intranets:last-child" );
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it using CSS?

Answer (score 0):

use Pseudo selector

$( ".local-intranets:first" ).

[More info](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

1. One option is using `.first() and .last()`

```js
$('.local-intranets').first().css('color','red')
$('.local-intranets').last().css('color','red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="abc">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="scriptWPQ22">
        <table id="Hero-WPQ22" dir="none" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" summary="MeetTheTeam" class="greenroom-meettheteam">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="ms-list-addnew ms-textLarge ms-soften"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div></div>
        <iframe src="javascript:false;" id="FilterIframe49" name="FilterIframe49" style="display:none" height="0" width="0" filterlink="?"></iframe>
        <div class="local-intranets">
          <div class="local-intranets-title">Budapest
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="local-intranets">
          <div class="local-intranets-title">Moscow</div>
        </div>
        <div class="local-intranets">
          <div class="local-intranets-title">Stockholm
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="local-intranets">
          <div class="local-intranets-title">Warsaw
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `filter()` and `:first` and `:last` selectors

```js
$('.local-intranets').filter(':first, :last').css('color','red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="abc">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="scriptWPQ22">
                <table id="Hero-WPQ22" dir="none" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" summary="MeetTheTeam" class="greenroom-meettheteam">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="ms-list-addnew ms-textLarge ms-soften"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div></div>
                <iframe src="javascript:false;" id="FilterIframe49" name="FilterIframe49" style="display:none" height="0" width="0" filterlink="?"></iframe>
                <div class="local-intranets">
                    <div class="local-intranets-title">Budapest
                            </div>
                </div>
                <div class="local-intranets">
                    <div class="local-intranets-title">Moscow</div>
                </div>
                <div class="local-intranets">
                    <div class="local-intranets-title">Stockholm
                                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="local-intranets">
                    <div class="local-intranets-title">Warsaw
                                        </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it using CSS?

Comment: Can use `:first-of-type` and `:last-of-type` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type

Answer (score 0):

you can use `last()` or `first()` to do that. for example to change the color of first and last element of local-intranets class you can do this:

```
$( ".local-intranets" ).last().css( "color", "red" );
$( ".local-intranets" ).first().css( "color", "red" );
```